# Send message through parallel whatsapp to unsaved number

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapi

I'm trying to send message through Whatsapp to unsaved number, I have two whatsapps and I'm getting the chooser but not able to add number to it, it shows my recent contact list.

I've tried Uri, PackageManager, and lots of things but no output

```
num = "91" + edt_num.getText().toString();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi, This is me");
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", num + "@s.whatsapp.net");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error/n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
}
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this Function for Sending Message to Unsaved number

> Must use country code in phoneNumber, e.g.91xxxxxxxxxx

```
public void SendWhatsappMessage(String phoneNumber,String message){
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent send= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        try {
            String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+ phoneNumber +"&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
            send.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            send.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            if (send.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
                startActivity(send);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering but I'm already able to send messages, what I want is, I want to send through my dual Whatsapp or parallel Whatsapp.... Please help

Comment: mean you have two whatsapp application in your phone, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's the issue

Comment: okay now you are find the packagename of both whatsapp. and replace that in my code . it ll be work

Comment: That's the issue because package names for bath are exactly same, but the storage location is different

Comment: share that two application link please, and second thing your phone is rooted?

Comment: I'm using a Samsung phone and it is a built-in feature to use two apps, no root required

Comment: can you show me that 2 apps . ? or share with me that apk files

Comment: i am stuck on the same problem did you resolved it???